# Type"X' is not assignable to type "Y" with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm new in TS, and I tried to use it with the context API, but I encountered this problem: when I try to pass the value in the provider I end up with this problem :

> "Type '{ players: Player[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Player[]'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'players' does
> not exist in type 'Player[]'.ts(2322)"

Here is my code :

```
interface Player {
  players: [];
}

type WithChildren<T = {}> = T & { children: JSX.Element };

const PlayersProvider = ({ children }: WithChildren) => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState<Player[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get<{ players: Player[] }>(baseUrl + "/players").then((response) => {
      setPlayers(response.data.players);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <PlayerContext.Provider value={{ players }}>
      {children};
    </PlayerContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

It worked fine when I had it in component but since I externalize in a context provider it broke.
Can someone explain me what's wrong?

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(response.data.players)`?

Comment: Which line is that error pointing to? What does your context definition look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are passing `{ players }` (of type `{ players: Player[]; }`) instead of `players` (of type `Player[]`) as a value to the context provider.

You should replace:

```
<PlayerContext.Provider value={{ players }}>
```

by:

```
<PlayerContext.Provider value={players}>
```

Comment: I tried that but it give me an error where I need to consume the context 
`const usePlayer = () => useContext(PlayerContext);
const { players } = usePlayer();`
give me the error _Property 'players' does not exist on type 'Player[]'.ts(2339)_

Comment: You should rather do `const players = usePlayer();` as now the list of players is the value of the context.